# How to verify a lnurl-auth callback with python

Tags: lightning-network, signature, python, secp256k1

I want to create a Python implementation of an lnurl-auth server.

I started a quick HTTP server to be the callback url, and captured the signed callback sent by BLW on Android.

```
?tag=login
&k1=7c27131e7fb37df50d12b0cb56ac1b76f817a5ba535b15afe43390a1f6b55d4d
&sig=30450221008172a00276a4724909b37051e98b36ba4f465aac82dd4d9609f91a3cd3be1a32022075bffd8d7697d140055b27e67d31a606435fdf5073c9c96d46a02cae06a5abc4&key=030f12794ae14407b8e1bfa1cbc297bb68ce6b24455ceab52c02da7a92782b6b14
```

Here is some python that attempts to verify that signature.

```
import secp256k1

k1 = bytes.fromhex("7c27131e7fb37df50d12b0cb56ac1b76f817a5ba535b15afe43390a1f6b55d4d")
key = bytes.fromhex('030f12794ae14407b8e1bfa1cbc297bb68ce6b24455ceab52c02da7a92782b6b14')
sig = bytes.fromhex('30450221008172a00276a4724909b37051e98b36ba4f465aac82dd4d9609f91a3cd3be1a32022075bffd8d7697d140055b27e67d31a606435fdf5073c9c96d46a02cae06a5abc4')


pubkey = secp256k1.PublicKey(key, raw=True)
sig = pubkey.ecdsa_deserialize(sig)
print(pubkey.ecdsa_verify(k1, sig))
```

`Output: False`

I don't know enough to tell what I'm doing wrong. It seems like this should be fairly standard use of the secp256k1 library.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up using the secp256k1 library, but here is a working python solution:

Make sure to install the `python-ecdsa` package, for instance with pip:

`pip install ecdsa`

...and then...

```
import ecdsa

k1 = bytes.fromhex('b29fa5994dc9da9906a36f996e6ac4faa2b0e2601ef13b0fab9d4b4287c57e1f')
key = bytes.fromhex('030f12794ae14407b8e1bfa1cbc297bb68ce6b24455ceab52c02da7a92782b6b14')
sig = bytes.fromhex('3045022100a23fbcaf3f24aff085d8c86a744764be8390e8511eca675ae2af037f33ff1a92022035f00465fbcad73e3175d7dc2e891322fa9dcce7bbd19409866f855e6da1f51e')

vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(key, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
vk.verify_digest(sig, k1, sigdecode=ecdsa.util.sigdecode_der)
```

With the `ecdsa` library, make sure to use `verify_digest` rather than `verify`.